# List component functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

Just wondering if anyone could take a look at my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3w56rrp94) on sandbox to help me with a problem I have been struggling with.

SelectList

- Display a full list of options to add to the List
- Display Pre-selected options (items with a value > 0)
- Updated when data changes, simulated on code sandbox with buttons
- Remove Item, item object needs too stay in item arry, value set to 0
- Item should only remove onClick of a button, (my version deletes if the user types deletes data in input)
- Add Item List should keep to its original order

Would really appreciate any help,

Shane

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? Just stating your app requirements and linking to a code sandbox means we'll have to figure that out. The more info you give about your errors, the more likely you are to get help. For each error you're facing, describe the intended functionality, the erroneous functionality you're getting with your current code, things you've tried to fix it, the specific place in the code the error seems to be (doesn't have to be down to a specific line, but try narrow it down as much as you can) as well as any error messages you get.